# Vim - calling buffer events when moving to other window with same buffer

Tags: vim, view, split, buffer, autocmd

if I have a file open in vim and use the command ":split", it splits the same buffer into two windows.

In my vimrc I have this commands:

```
autocmd BufEnter * set cursorline
autocmd BufEnter * set cursorcolumn
autocmd BufLeave * set nocursorline
autocmd BufLeave * set nocursorcolumn
```

Unfortunattely they are not executed when I move from one window to another window if the window holds the same buffer.

How can I execute those commands, when I move to another window, even if the buffer is the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`WinEnter`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#WinEnter)/ `WinLeave` instead. As the former doesn't fire on startup, you may need `VimEnter` as well.

Note that there are also plugin solutions for showing `'cursorline'` just in the current window, for example my [CursorLineCurrentWindow plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4178) (the next version 2.00 will support `'cursorcolumn'` and `'wincolor'` as well) and [cursorline_current.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5740).